# Drawing the volume generated by three vectors

Tags: list-manipulation, geometry

I have three vectors:

```
v1={1,0,0}       v1={0,1,0}     v1=1/2{1,1,1}
```

I wish to show the volume constructed by these vectors.

I know the amount of this volume is calculated by

```
1/2  Dot[Cross[{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}], {1, 1, 1}]
```

But I do not know how to draw this volume!!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To include the vectors in the drawing:

```
v = {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, 1/2 {1, 1, 1}};

ℛ = Parallelepiped[{0, 0, 0}, v];

Graphics3D[{
  {Opacity[0.7], ℛ},
  {Red, Arrowheads[0.05],
   Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, #}, 0.01]] & /@ v}},
 Axes -> True,
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

[image]

The volume can be calculated multiple ways

```
{Volume[ℛ], RegionMeasure[ℛ], Integrate[1, {x, y, z} ∈ ℛ]}

(* {1/2, 1/2, 1/2} *)

SameQ @@ %

(* True *)
```

Answer (score 8):

Use `Parallelepiped`:

```
v1 = {1, 0, 0};
v2 = {0, 1, 0};
v3 = 1/2 {1, 1, 1};
Graphics3D[Parallelepiped[{0, 0, 0}, {v1, v2, v3}]]
```

[image: Plot of parallelepiped]

Comment: Thank you so much. But How to show this volume in a cubic with sides equal to 1

Comment: Assuming you mean the aspect ratio, `Show[Graphics3D[Parallelepiped[{0, 0, 0}, {v1, v2, v3}]], BoxRatios -> 1]`.